# Sender name of Variant gives an error 438 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Each day, I and a coworker get a mail with the same format.

I want to import the time/date of the mail and the subject if the mail meets the following requirements:

- Subject contains "Order"
- Received time >= (Based on range)
- Received time <= (Based on range)
- Specific Sender name (Based on range)

The code works when I use my own Outlook account. When a coworker tries to run it, the condition of the specific sender name gives an error

> 438 'Object doesn't support this property or method'.

When I remove the condition of the specific sender name, the code works on my coworker's account. The sender name in my coworker's account is the same as in my own Outlook account.
(Obviously, the strMailboxName and the Folders have been changed into the names my coworker uses in Outlook before trying to run the code.)

Note: my coworker has Calendar appointments in the Folder, which I don't have (but they are not sent by SenderName). Furthermore, my coworker receives mails about other subjects from SenderName.

```
Sub Outlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim strMailboxName As String
Dim i As Integer

strMailboxName = "OutlookName" 'Name of mailaccount
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set Folder = Session.Folders(strMailboxName)
Set Folder = Folder.Folders("FolderName") 'Name of folder

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Order") > 0 And   OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("start_date").Value And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime <= Range("end_date") And OutlookMail.Sender = Range("Sender") Then

        Range("Date_and_time").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("Date_and_time").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        Range("Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

        i = i + 1

    End If
Next OutlookMail
Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Why does this occur and how do I overcome this problem? Is this a code problem or perhaps a problem with some sort of settings of my coworker's mail account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never loop through *all* items in a folder - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

Secondly, you can have items other than `MailItem` in a folder - you can also have `ReportItem` (for NDRs) and `MeetingItem` (for appointment invitations/updates).
Do check that `OutlookMail.Class` property = 43 (`olMailItem`) first.

Comment: Your suggestion about Items.Find / FindNext work great, makes the macro a lot faster. 
The 438 error is indeed solved by checking the OutlookMail.Class property first.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!